# CSS width and margins don't add up with media query

Tags: html, css, margin

I am building a blog layout. The goal is to have content centered in the window, and justified, with a maximum width and a minimum distance to the border of the window.

I have gotten this working with a combination of `max-width` and a media query to set margins at a certain threshold. I tried putting both `max-width` and fixed `margin-left` and `margin-right` together, but this failed.

So, I've gone with the solution below, where I have a `max-width` combined with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`, and separately I have a media query where I set `margin-left: 2em; margin-right; 2em`.

This works mostly fine, but I am very confused about the media query I've had to define to get this to work seamlessly. CSS is below and you can see a sample page [here](https://www.antifound.com/test.html).

I expect that with `max-width: 55em;` for my content, and a media query that kicks in at `(max-width: 59em)` and margins on either side of 2em, that there should be a seamless transition, with the text never touching the border of the window.

With the version below, I get to a transition point where the text touches the edge of the window for a range of size before the margins kick in and the text retracts from the edge. I figured 55+4=59, and so at 59, I get 4em total of borders, and the text should recede from the edge at that point, as I resize my window smaller; this does not happen.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 59em) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 59em) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <article>
      Here is a nice long paragraph which should
      certainly hit the wrap limit.
      It should do this because it is a long paragraph,
      with more words and characters than fit in the
      maximum width configured for this page.
      I have written multiple sentences in a row, to
      ensure that this will take ample screen space horizontally.
      I am good at writing like this.
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

The value that works as I intend is below, and you can see a version [here](https://www.antifound.com/test2.html). Here I have everything the same, except for the media query: `(max-width: 80em)`. I got here purely through guessing and checking. If I resize my window down, I see a smooth transition where the text never approaches the window border, or touches it.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 80em) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 80em) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <article>
      Here is a nice long paragraph which should
      certainly hit the wrap limit.
      It should do this because it is a long paragraph,
      with more words and characters than fit in the
      maximum width configured for this page.
      I have written multiple sentences in a row, to
      ensure that this will take ample screen space horizontally.
      I am good at writing like this.
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, my question is one, some, or all of the below:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. What is the math that makes 80-4=55?
3. How should this goal be achieved instead?

**Edit:** Adding some gifs, because I was bad at explaining this.

Here is bad: note that there is a period of time as I'm resizing where the text is bang up against the window border. I don't want this. I expect that the 2x2em margins, which kick in at a width of 59em should start having an effect. Instead, there is a period, during resizing (aka some population of certain window sizes) where the text is bang against the window border.

[image: bad margin behavior]

And here's the good one. This has a media query with `max-width: 80em`. This has the behavior I want. See how the text never hits the window border, just smoothly starts retreating from it. 80em is the magic number (at least for me viewing from multiple browsers on my desktop - I do not know if this is a me-problem). Less, and I get the text approaching closer to the border and then it snaps to my 2em margins. More, and it is left-aligned, rather than centered.

[image: good margin behavior]

Comment: (PS) I like your website so far : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    /* something else */
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, doloremque iste sequi est autem officia asperiores, illo, vero reiciendis incidunt provident itaque laborum quidem! Aut nisi eaque a itaque numquam.</p>
</section>
```

Maybe it's a border-box issue....

https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Added gifs. I am not good at explaining visual things. I am trying your suggestion presently.

Comment: It's hard to explain layouts! : )

Comment: It's a mindset change for this small-screen-first CSS stuff.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I've got the same issue, where there is a magic set of values that I cannot figure out the math on to make the transition smooth, like I want. If I guess the right `max-width` on the .container class and the right `max-width` in the media query, I can get the result I want. I don't like guessing, though. Any thoughts on why, when I define it in terms of em that it doesn't seem to add up?

Comment: Well, I don't think you should use ems here - for one thing... and also I'm not sure what you want to happen still. There are only 2 numbers / 20px and auto, right? It might be a border-box issue? edited answer...

Comment: Ack, I had left my media query in ems and did the width in pixels. So, yes, pixels add up and work to keep the text off the window border as I resize. My goal was to stay away from px and pt, though, as I do want this to scale decently. On large screens I want to limit roughly on words per line, rather than fixed size across the window. My understanding was that ems are the unit for that. I am happy to be told I am wrong.

Comment: Well... you could use `vw` units for that. As someone who has gone through many phases of units - I'd suggest you stick with pxl for almost everything. no units for line-height - and ems for letter-spacing only. But - it's up to you!

Comment: Text justification is generally hard to read in most cases - but we all try it for a while first. ; )

Comment: Here's just something else to think about: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4us1Ln7g/ - while your issue may have been leaky styles - they wouldn't be leaking in a targeted example like this. I also think that "whey doesn't numbers add up" is a red flag - and that you might be overcomplicating it. I hope this helps! : )

Comment: That is much better! And it seems to solve my next problem, which was getting `<pre>` blocks to play nicely with my width settings. Thanks! HTML and CSS are things I have actively avoided in much of my work, so I am definitely fumbling around. I appreciate your many followups and helpful tips.

Comment: @greggyb - join us in the CSS discord if you want to learn more https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH
 : )

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What am I doing wrong here?
> 2. What is the math that makes 80-4=55?

The main problem is that the media query uses the styling for the document, not the `container` class. This means that `1em` in the query is different than `1em` in the `container` div. For example, this snippet uses the same styling for the text that the document uses, so it works. Note that I also set the body's margin to 0 because the margin of the body is also included in the media query. This solution, as I'm sure you'll agree, is not the desired result.

**Not-So-Good Version**

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55em;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 59em) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <article>
      Here is a nice long paragraph which should
      certainly hit the wrap limit.
      It should do this because it is a long paragraph,
      with more words and characters than fit in the
      maximum width configured for this page.
      I have written multiple sentences in a row, to
      ensure that this will take ample screen space horizontally.
      I am good at writing like this.
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

> 3. How should this goal be achieved instead?

Instead, I would recommend a flexbox. Set the `container` class style to be just

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

and move the other styling to the `content` class. Set the margin of the `content` class to `auto 2em`. (see the snippet below)

**Good Flexbox Version**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  margin: auto 2em;
  max-width: 55em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <article>
      Here is a nice long paragraph which should
      certainly hit the wrap limit.
      It should do this because it is a long paragraph,
      with more words and characters than fit in the
      maximum width configured for this page.
      I have written multiple sentences in a row, to
      ensure that this will take ample screen space horizontally.
      I am good at writing like this.
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: css-tricks.com has a [good resource for understanding flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I did cycle through something similar on the margins, though not with a flexbox. Trying your code, I end up with the issue in larger windows where the content is not centered, but is left-aligned (with the margin), so I get a big whitespace to the right. Is there a way using flexbox to keep the whole deal centered horizontally when the screen is large?

Comment: May I ask what browser you are testing in?

Comment: Latest Chrome and Firefox. The content is only centered when the viewport is roughly max-width + margin. When the viewport is wider than that, the content is margin length from the left, but the right whitespace is unbounded.

Comment: It works in the snippet for me on Chrome 77 and Firefox 69. If you are testing on your website, try the snippet in my answer. Does the snippet work? If so, there must be inherited styles messing it up.

Comment: You are probably right, if it's working on yours. I will take a look in the morning again. You are correct that I'm embedding in my site. I thought I had stripped out everything else affecting these classes, but I may have missed one.

Comment: I had a chance to review again today. Your solution works. I took out all my pre-existing CSS and added it back bit by bit. I had set up some margins elsewhere, like you had suggested. Thanks for your help.